# Using only serif as font in CSS

Tags: css, fonts

Have I understod the following right?

```
font-family:sans-serif;
```

Above will result in the default sans-serif font installed on the computer. Which is arial on PC and Helvetica on Mac as tandard.

```
font-family:serif;
```

Above will result in the default serif font installed on the computer.

Which is the default "serif font" on Mac and on PC?

Comment: Which is the default font on mac and PC if you don't specify font-family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, it's Times New Roman. On Mac, it's Times, though it may be Times New Roman as well.

Comment: Thanks minitech, do you know the default font if you skip specifying font-family?

Comment: @Hakan: It varies by browser and OS so you should always specify it explicitly, but it's usually the Serif font. On Linux, it's the Sans-serif font by default usually.

Comment: @Hakan: Could you unaccept this answer so I can delete it, please? It’s wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The generic font names such as `serif` denote implementation-dependent fonts, but the font then depends on the browser and its settings. It may also depend on the natural language used in the document when marked up (using the `lang` or `xml:lang` attribute).

Usually the default serif font is Times New Roman on PCs, Times on Macs.

**Edit:** On IE, in some versions, it appears to be Batang; see
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34399/unknown-css-font-family-oddity-with-ie7-10-on-windows-vista-7-8

Comment: Ahaaa it's browser specific. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

The exact font used for 'serif' and 'sans-serif' depends on the browser. Most browsers will allow users to configure these settings, and (usually) default to Times New Roman (and its variants) for serifs, Arial / Helvetica for sans-serifs. Default fonts in Linux distributions vary.

If a buggy browser attempts to use a font that doesn't exist on the machine, most operating systems will degrade gracefully and use a typical system font. That's very unlikely to come into practice, though.

Because different clients and user-agents can use fonts with very different spacing and proportions, it becomes important to try and avoid using the generic 'sans-serif' and 'serif' fonts for em-based layouts.